# How to use automorphism of Group to define automorphism of its factor group?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group and $T$ an automorphism of $G.$ If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $T(N)\subset N,$ then how to use this $T$ to define an automorphism of $G/N?$
In this problem I get stuck. I have no idea to how to start a solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First I would note that you can strengthen the condition $T(N)\subset N$ to $T(N)=N$ since the map is a bijection. Then the factor group is $G/T(N)$.

Comment: do you need to strengthen the condition? The natural definition is $T(gN)=T(g)N$, you just need to check this satisfies the definition of an automorphism

Comment: Following what Robert Chamberlain says, you will also have to check that it is well-defined, in addition to checking that it is an automorphism. This is one of the reasons you need $T(N) = N$.

Comment: In general $T(N) \le N$ does not imply $T(N)=N$.

Comment: @Derek Holt,Why Sir? As T is automorphism Which  isomorphism onto itself therefore must be bijective. so even if we take that on N it should follow.Where is mistake in my argument ?

Comment: As an example, let $G = ({\mathbb Q},+)$, $N = ({\mathbb Z},+)$, and $T(x) = 2x$ for $x \in G$.

Comment: Sorry Sir Mis reading of your statement

Comment: It is onto and it is an automorphism.

Comment: Thanks a Lot .That means by even weaker assumption we can do that problem

Comment: (If $G$ is finite then $T(N)\leq N\Rightarrow T(N)=N$. Also, "$G$ is finite" can be replaced here with either "$N$ is finite" or "$N$ has finite index in $G$".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a natural roadmap:

Let $\overline G=G/N$ and define $\overline T: \overline G \to \overline G$ by $\overline T(\overline g) = \overline {T(g)}$. Now prove:

- $\overline T$ is well-defined.
- $\overline T$ is a homomorphism.
- $\overline T$ is an automorphism.

The only real nontrivial point is that $\overline T$ is injective. For that, we need $T(N)=N$.

Comment: This problem assumes that $T(N)\subset N$ holds but don't assumes that $T(N)=N$. So, I think we cannot show $\overline{T}$ is injective.